# Meaning of a Dirac delta speed in 1d shallow-water equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, mathematical-physics, conservation-laws, velocity

A 1d thin layer of a fluid of constant density in hydrostatic balance can be modeled by shallow-water equations:

$$\begin{align*}\partial_tu+\partial_x\left(v+\frac{u^2}{2}\right)&=0,\\ \partial_tv+\partial_x(u+uv)&=0,\end{align*}$$

where $u(x,t)$ denotes the horizontal fluid velocity and $v(x,t)$ denotes the deflection of the free surface from its rest position.

Does a speed profile $u(x,t)$ containing a Dirac delta function have physical meaning?

More generally, are there physical systems modeled by a velocity field containing a Dirac delta function?

Comment: In pipelines with wormholes. The delta-function velocity means that $x$ jumps discontinuously at the given place or time.

Comment: You could have a step function (e.g., discontinuity like a shock) where its derivative is a Dirac delta function.